# (Breaking Again) The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first. (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I've been using facebook sdk for over a year now and i had followed the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) accordingly but since yesterday the app started throwing the error and it's also occurring in the previous release build (Which was running fine till yesterday). I checked the other answers which suggest adding the string in the manifest file but that has already been added & on iOS it's working fine.

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.FacebookSdkNotInitializedException
The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized (Validate.kt:129)
com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLoggerImpl.<init> (AppEventsLoggerImpl.kt:642)
com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLoggerImpl.<init> (AppEventsLoggerImpl.kt:82)
com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.<init> (AppEventsLogger.kt:118)
com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.<init>
com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger$Companion.newLogger (AppEventsLogger.kt:369)
com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.newLogger (Unknown Source:2)
com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBAppEventsLoggerModule.initialize (FBAppEventsLoggerModule.java:129)
com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.doInitialize (ModuleHolder.java:236)
com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.markInitializable (ModuleHolder.java:100)
com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceInitialized (NativeModuleRegistry.java:129)
com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$2.run (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:452)
```

Comment: What SDK version are you using?

Comment: @Zach using the latest one `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release`

Comment: any update on solution of this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently client token was missing, adding that fixed it

Ref: https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/issues/236#issuecomment-1111744717